# How to set enum AllowTabbedDocks with PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

I want to make a QMainWindow for my PyQt5 app. I want to use `AllowTabbedDocks`, but for this I need to set `AllowTabbedDocks` to `True`. I cannot figue out how to do this.

From the Qt documenttation, I found these two methods:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        .....
        self.setDockOption()
        self.DockOptions()
```

Available flags in QMainWindow class are as follow:

```
AllowNestedDocks = 2
AllowTabbedDocks = 4
AnimatedDocks = 1
ForceTabbedDocks = 8
GroupedDragging = 32
VerticalTabs = 16
```

My question is how can I use:

```
dockOptions()
setDockOption()
```

of the `QMainWindow` class? My question may be weird, because I am unable to understand properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the dock options have `AllowTabbedDocks` and `AnimatedDocks` already set, so you don't need to do anything. Several options can be combined into one using [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

You can test whether an option is set by using the `&` (AND) operator:

```
print(bool(self.dockOptions() & QMainWindow.AllowTabbedDocks))
```

to remove an option, use the `~` (NOT) operator:

```
self.setDockOptions(self.dockOptions() & ~QMainWindow.AllowTabbedDocks)
```

to add an option, use the `|` (OR) operator:

```
self.setDockOptions(self.dockOptions() | QMainWindow.AllowTabbedDocks)
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped